# Each Thread should pick 95% of time valid id and remaining 5% of time non valid id

Tags: java, multithreading, random, executorservice

I am working on a project in which I am supposed to read the few properties from a file. Below is my propertie file-

```
NUMBER_OF_THREADS: 10
RANGE_VALID_USER_ID: 1-5000
RANGE_NON_VALID_USER_ID: 10000-50000
PERCENTAGE_VALID_USER_ID: 95
```

Now that means from the above properties, `number of threads` is `10`, and then range of `valid user id's` is from `1 to 5000`, and range of `non valid user id` is from `10000-50000`, and most important thing `95% of time` each thread should choose id from valid user id range which means remaining `5% of time` it will choose id from non valid user id range.

Below is my program that I have wrote. It will read the above property file.

```
private static Properties prop = new Properties();
private static int threads;
private static int startValidRange;
private static int endValidRange;
private static int startNonValidRange;
private static int endNonValidRange;
private static double percentageValidId;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create thread pool with given size
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

    try {
        readPropertyFile();

        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
            service.submit(new ReadTask());
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}

private static void readPropertyFile() throws IOException {

    prop.load(Read.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));

    threads = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("NUMBER_OF_THREADS"));

    startValidRange = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("RANGE_VALID_USER_ID").split("-")[0]);
    endValidRange = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("RANGE_VALID_USER_ID").split("-")[1]);

    startNonValidRange = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("RANGE_NON_VALID_USER_ID").split("-")[0]);
    endNonValidRange = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("RANGE_NON_VALID_USER_ID").split("-")[1]);

    percentageValidId = Double.parseDouble(prop.getProperty("PERCENTAGE_VALID_USER_ID"));
}
```

Below is my `ReadTask class` that implements `Runnable Interface`.

```
class ReadTask implements Runnable {

    public ReadTask() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long endTime = startTime + (durationOfRun*60*1000);    

    while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {

    /* Print valid user id 95% of time 
     * and remaining 5% of time it will print 
     * non valid user id.
     */

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in my run method currently, each thread will be running for a particular period of time and in that particular period of time, it will choose valid user id 95% of time and remaining 5% of time, it will choose non valid user id.

**My Question:-**

Currently I am stuck on this problem, how to make sure each thread will use 95% of time valid user id and remaining 5% of time, it will choose non valid user id.

Please let me know if I am not clear in any of the part. Any suggestions will be of great help in solving this problem.

Comment: What is your task supposed to print? A **random** value (in those ranges, given the proportion)?

Comment: Exactly. Yeah any random value in those ranges given the proportion.

Comment: we know that `SecureRandom` returns a uniform distribution of numbers so all you need to do is generate random numbers [1-100] and if the number is <= 95 then read from valid; otherwise generate from invalid.

Comment: Does it really matter if the selection of an invalid one is randomly distributed?  Counting to 20 is pretty easy to implement :)

Comment: @bmorris591, I see. That makes more sense. Can you provide me any example, like how to read from valid if random numbers is less than 95? And what data structure I should use for valid range and non valid range?

Comment: print 19 valid ones, 1 invalid one, rinse, repeat until time is up.

Comment: @FarhanJamal Since all the properties set in `readPropertyFile` are private, to access it `ReadTask` must be an inner class. It is, right? BTW, have you tried something already?

Comment: @Brian Roach. Thanks Brian for the suggestion. Can you also suggest me what data structure I should be using here for valid range and non valid range? And it will be of great help if you can provide some example by which I will be able to understand better. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, I was confused first of all which data structure I was supposed to use here for valid range or non valid range. I was also sure that somehow I need to use Randomness here. But how to club these two things together was causing me problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure you chose if fine, just make sure the static fields are accessible to `ReadTask` (by either making them `public`/"package protected", or by making `ReadTask` an inner class). To choose your numbers, first randomize the choice between "valid" or "invalid" (as suggested by @bmorris591). Then get a random integer, but "shifted" to match your interval:

```
Random r = new SecureRandom();
while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {
    int randomID;
    if ( r.nextFloat() < percentageValidId/100 )
        randomID = r.nextInt(endValidRange - startValidRange + 1) + startValidRange;
    else
        randomID = r.nextInt(endNonValidRange - startNonValidRange + 1) + startNonValidRange;
    // Print it
}
```

Comment: Add 1 to your id generators - the `nextInt` method does not include the upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

Have caution when accesing member variables like endTime from threads. If the variable isn't final, you should synchronize its access or, if it's going to be modified only in one thread, make it transient.

Comment: Thanks Igor for the suggestion. I have updated the question by adding two lines that I missed previously in my code. Can you take a look now whether it looks good now or not?